# Filtering the rows of a pivot table

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have generated this [Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr6lz.jpg) and would like to be able to select the country in which there are (Export & Import) entries for every month of the year 2014, where the period 201401 represents the month of January 2014, 201402 February 2014 etc. 
Obviously in this case it is only Ireland in this example but I would like to be able to do find it programmatically just in case I come across an instance where I cannot do it by sight. I have tried filtering and grouping techniques and using the len function but these are only applicable to the columns of a data frame and not the rows?

Comment: You might as well include some actual code, so the reader can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the index, so that you can manipulate them as columns. For example, you could try:

```
milk_keypartners_pivot6 = milk_keypartners_pivot6.reset_index()
groupedCount = (milk_keypartners_pivot6.groupby('Partner')['Trade Flow'].count() == 12)
countries_with_12 = groupedCount[groupedCount == True].index
milk_keypartners_pivot6 = milk_keypartners_pivot6[milk_keypartners_pivot6['Partner'].isin(countries_with_12)]
```

Comment: After using `reset_index()` I filtered using a function I had defined involving `len()`